# Angular's $watchCollection vs AngularFire's $watch

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using angularfire with an array like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
var sync = $firebase(ref);
$rootScope.list = sync.$asArray();
```

I want to know the difference between using angular's $watchCollection
on 'list' and using angularfire built-in $watch like this:

```
$rootScope.list.$watch(function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Which one is faster and what are the use cases of each one?

Comment: Don't use $watch unless you have a compelling use case to do so. The point of AngularFire is to take care of things like this on your behalf. AngularFire's $watch is triggered for different use cases than Angular's. You'll want to read the APIs and use the appropriate one for your (undisclosed) use case and not worry about faster or slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about AngularFire as a service wrapper around the Firebase API. It augments and uses features of Angular, but ultimately is meant to help you integrate back to Firebase. That being said...

- `scope.$watchCollection()` [according to the spec](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) "shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change". It works on arrays and object maps, but watches only those objects that are held by your client.
- `x.$watch` in AngularFire is really more an abstraction of functions that enable the 'three way data bind' feature. Note that `$watch` is used for both [$FirebaseObject](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-watchcallback-context) and [$FirebaseArray](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-watchcb-context) - it does different things in each context, but essentially enable you to keep your data in the client in sync with updates on your server/Firebase.
- Considering the different roles, 'faster' is not really an appropriate question. If you are using `$watch` in AngularFire, you would not need to use `$watchCollection` on the same object. For what it's worth, AngularFire's `$watch` is actually pretty speedy.